# JSON data and php RecursiveArrayIterator

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON response from an API in the following format:

```
string(2228) "{"question":{"type":"single","text":"Have you noticed any insects on you or have you been bitten by any insect (lice, mosquitoes, ticks, bedbugs, etc.)?",
"items":
[
{"id":"p_48","name":"Insect bite","
choices":
[{"id":"present","label":"Yes"},
{"id":"absent","label":"No"},
{"id":"unknown","label":"Don't know"}
]}
],
"extras":{}
},
"conditions":[
{"id":"c_87","name":"Common cold","common_name":"Common cold","probability":0.028},
{"id":"c_10","name":"Gastroenteritis","common_name":"Gastroenteritis","probability":0.0238},
{"id":"c_49","name":"Migraine","common_name":"Migraine","probability":0.0096}
],
"extras":{},"should_stop":false}"
```

I need to get the **question -> text**,

**id and choices**

&& **conditions with id, name and probability**.

I tried the following:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("test.json");
//var_dump($str);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

No output. I also tried the php RecursiveArrayIterator as follows:

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

and get error message that:

```
Passed variable is not an array or object
```

I am new to php and unable to understand the reason ?? Help solicited from experts.

**Update:**

I called CURL directly from terminal and found that it was missing the `string(2228) "`and the trailing `"` part. So i did explode and substr. Since it is a multi-dimenisonal array i did the recursive array iterator as follows:

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($str, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

Go the output required. Issue resolved.

Comment: check var_dump on $str on second line, I guess your file_get_contents is not reading your json file or the path is incorrect, is in the same directory where this file is running?

Comment: @pravindot17 I had checked var_dump earlier. It was working fine.

Comment: @Pamela you get the NULL array as you have the error in JSON structure.

Comment: @Nazir Could you please spell out the error. It is coming from an API and i just copied it to a file.

Comment: That's not valid json up there.

Comment: @kerbholz I have mailed the API provider regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy this code in your test file and then get the result:

**here is the error in JSON syntax:**

```
"name": "Insect bite",
            "
            choices "
```

**Try bellow code sample**

```
{
    "question": {
        "type": "single",
        "text": "Have you noticed any insects on you or have you been bitten by any insect (lice, mosquitoes, ticks, bedbugs, etc.)?",
        "items": [{
            "id": "p_48",
            "name": "Insect bite",
            "choices": [{
                    "id": "present",
                    "label": "Yes"
                },
                {
                    "id": "absent",
                    "label": "No"
                },
                {
                    "id": "unknown",
                    "label": "Don't know"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "extras": {}
    },
    "conditions": [{
            "id": "c_87",
            "name": "Common cold",
            "common_name": "Common cold",
            "probability": 0.028
        },
        {
            "id": "c_10",
            "name": "Gastroenteritis",
            "common_name": "Gastroenteritis",
            "probability": 0.0238
        },
        {
            "id": "c_49",
            "name": "Migraine",
            "common_name": "Migraine",
            "probability": 0.0096
        }
    ],
    "extras": {},
    "should_stop": false
}
```

Comment: As informed the result is coming from an external API and i am testing it copying it to a file. Please note that changing the JSON is not the way to go. And using your JSON does not provide CHOICES.

Comment: if we test original JSON code from your sample with decoding we get error `Unexpected control character found`

Comment: try `json_decode($str);` then print `json_last_error());` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8); gives
NULL bool(false)

Comment: and var_dump(json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg());
gives int(4) string(12) "Syntax error"

Comment: yes, there is the Syntax error in your sample - to clarify do you get this answer from URL?

Comment: Yes..I just copied it from url. ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160940/discussion-between-nazir-and-pamela).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, see here I am able access your json properties

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7gc8n");
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// checkout this I am getting json here
echo '<pre>';
// print_r($json, true);

print_r($json['question']['text']);
print_r($json['conditions']);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: I am not getting any result ??